# What to do with DNS if IP address is changed?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2016, local-area-network

I'm working with Windows Server 2016 Essentials. Someone in the organization installed a Linksys mesh network into the router that our server was once plugged into. The Linksys parent node's DHCP is now assigning IP addresses. When the mesh network was installed, it obviously messed up the DNS server because it was configured to use a static IP so they went in and changed the local server to use DHCP instead of its static IP. The mesh network has an IP range of 10.182.1.0/24 and the old router was 192.168.1.0/24. Everything was working fine until the introduction of the mesh network and subsequent changing of the LAN. I am receiving the following error messages.

> Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associated with DNS domain 'ForestDnsZones.MyServer.local.' failed.  These records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application partition).

Possible causes of failure include:

- TCP/IP properties of the network connections of this computer contain the wrong IP address(es) of the preferred and alternate DNS servers
- Specified preferred and alternate DNS servers are not running
- DNS server(s) primary for the records to be registered is not running
- Preferred or alternate DNS servers are configured with wrong root hints
- Parent DNS zone contains incorrect delegation to the child zone authoritative for the DNS records that failed registration

**USER ACTION**
Fix possible misconfiguration(s) specified above and initiate registration or deletion of the DNS records by running 'nltest.exe /dsregdns' from the command prompt on the domain controller or by restarting Net Logon service on the domain controller.

The DNS server is waiting for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed. The DNS server service cannot start until the initial synchronization is complete because critical DNS data might not yet be replicated onto this domain controller. If events in the AD DS event log indicate that there is a problem with DNS name resolution, consider adding the IP address of another DNS server for this domain to the DNS server list in the Internet Protocol properties of this computer. This event will be logged every two minutes until AD DS has signaled that the initial synchronization has been successfully completed.

This computer is now hosting the specified directory instance, but Active Directory Web Services could not service it. Active Directory Web Services will retry this operation periodically.

Directory instance: NTDS
Directory instance LDAP port: 389
Directory instance SSL port: 636

**My question is would removing the AD DS and DNS roles and adding them back be the right solution.**

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is

Comment: `they went in and changed the local server to use DHCP instead of its static IP.` Change the IP address back to the previous address.

Comment: @GregAskew That doesn't work. The old IP range was 192.168.1.0/24 and the new one is 10.182.1.0/24. The new router does not allow you to change that IP range.

Comment: @RohitGupta My question is would removing the AD DS and DNS roles be the right solution.

Comment: What obviously doesn't work is changing the IP address of a domain controller. This is a failed network "upgrade". Act accordingly.

Comment: Uhm. Removing AD DS and DNS roles works if you want to remove those services... but the problem is basically that you have a network that smells more like a home network environment than a proper business network.

Comment: @vidarlo Would removing those roles and adding them back right after work?

Comment: @GregAskew I totally agree that this is a failed network "upgrade." It wasn't my doing and no one consulted with me before doing it. But unfortunately, I am the one that has to fix it.

Comment: Is this a new setup, or does it have useful data? You mention that the initial sync is ongoing?

Comment: @vidarlo Its not a new setup and it does have useful data. It had been setup and working smoothly since 2019. The useful data is on another drive fortunately so I could possibly rebuild the entire network from new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reread the question a few times and have an update.

Either create a DHCP reservation for the server in the Linksys mesh interface... If you have access to that.

If not, from a computer on the LinkSys network, ping 10.182.1.245.
If you don't receive a response, I'd say it's safe enough to hardcode that IP into your server. Set your server to 10.182.1.245, subnet 255.255.255.0, default gateway probably 10.182.1.245. You can confirm with ipconfig /all on a working computer using DHCP.

Once you have a DHCP reservation or have set the static IP of .245, reboot the server just to give the services a fresh start.
Then attempt the 3 commands below:

/update

If I understand correctly, the IP of the domain controller changed. In that case you need to run the following on the domain controller. I don't think removing and readding the AD and DNS roles will help you at all.

1- `ipconfig /flushdns`

2- `ipconfig /registerdns`

3- `dcdiag /fix`

Step 1 removes any cached DNS records on the local machine

Step 2 registers the servers new IP in DNS

Step 3 will update the SPN records in DNS